$\text{id}(m)\otimes\psi(y)=0\Rightarrow$ $\text{id}(m)=0$ or $\psi(y)=0$?
Here the author proves the following:

$M\otimes_R -$ is right-exact, meaning for a short exact sequence $$0\rightarrow X\overset{\varphi}{\rightarrow}Y\overset{\psi}{\rightarrow}Z\rightarrow 0$$ we get an exact sequence $$M\otimes_R X\overset{\Phi}{\rightarrow}M\otimes_R Y\overset{\Psi}{\rightarrow}M\otimes_R Z{\rightarrow}0$$

This is the authors proof:

Define $\Psi=\text{id}\otimes\psi$ and $\Phi=\text{id}\otimes\varphi$. In the case of $\Psi$ we know that if $\Psi(m\otimes y)=0$ then $\text{id}(m)=0$ or $\psi(y)=0$. Since both of these functions are surjective, $\Psi$ must be as well.
Now, to show that $\text{Im}(\Phi)=\ker(\Psi)$, let $\sum m_i\otimes y_i\in\text{Im}(\Phi)$. So for some $\sum m_i\otimes x_i$, $\Phi(\sum m_i\otimes x_i)=\sum m_i\otimes y_i$. This amounts to the fact that $m\otimes y=m\otimes\varphi(x)$ for some $x\in X$. Then $\Phi(\sum m_i\otimes\varphi(x_i))=\sum m_i\otimes\psi(\varphi(x_i))=\sum m_i\otimes 0=0$ by the exactness of the original sequence. So we have that $\text{Im}(\Phi)\subseteq\ker(\Psi)$. Now let $\sum m_j\otimes y_j\in\ker(\Psi)$, nontrivial. This means that $\sum m_j\otimes\psi(y_j)=0$ with nonzero $m$, and so $\psi(y)=0$. Since the original sequence is exact, this means that $y\in\text{Im}(\varphi)$, and so it must be the case that $m\otimes y\in\text{Im}(\Phi)$.

I wonder, how can the author conclude that $\text{id}(m)\otimes\psi(y)=0\Rightarrow$ $\text{id}(m)=0$ or $\psi(y)=0$? I'm not very familiar with the tensor product, but I have gotten the impression that it is hard in general to determine when it is zero. For instance, consider $1\otimes 1\in\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\otimes_\Bbb Z\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. We have that $$\begin{align}1\otimes 1&=1\otimes (2\cdot 2)\\&=2(1\otimes 2)\\&=2\otimes 2\\&=0\otimes 2\\&=0\end{align}$$ But $1\neq 0$.

...and since your computation can be extended to a counterexample (tensor $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \overset{\cdot 2}{\to} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ with $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$) the author's conclusion is, in fact, false (even though the statement they're trying to prove is correct).
